# Read overall database to check value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to check the overall database table to see if the content is equal to my value. If is equal to my value it will show the `<div>` tag. Now i success to show out the `<div>` tag. But it just read one value from the database, which is the first element of the database.
After I read the first element the function stops to search the next line. I would like to know how should I fix this problem? As I know I can store the search content into datatable and then retrieve it out 1 by 1, but I have no idea how to start it.
Here is my code. Any help will be appreciated.

```
public void showNotification()
{
    String MSGnotificationStatus = "";
    String PostNotificationStatus = "";
    try
    {
        MySqlConnection connStr = new MySqlConnection();
        connStr.ConnectionString = "Server = localhost; Database = healthlivin; Uid = root; Pwd = khei92;";
        String searchMesgNotification = "SELECT s.isRead FROM msgsession s, person m, contactfriend c WHERE m.PersonID = @pID AND m.PersonID = c.PersonID AND c.friendID = s.friendID";
        MySqlCommand cmdSearch = new MySqlCommand(searchMesgNotification, connStr);
        connStr.Open();
        cmdSearch.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pID", (String)Session["memberID"]);

        MySqlDataReader dtrRead = cmdSearch.ExecuteReader();

        if (dtrRead.Read())
        {
            MSGnotificationStatus = (String)dtrRead["isRead"];
        }

        dtrRead.Close();
        connStr.Close();

        String searchPostNotification = "SELECT p.isRead FROM post p, thread t, person m WHERE m.PersonID = @pID2 AND m.PersonID = t.PersonID AND t.threadID = p.threadID";
        MySqlCommand cmdSearch2 = new MySqlCommand(searchPostNotification, connStr);
        connStr.Open();
        cmdSearch2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pID2", (String)Session["memberID"]);

        MySqlDataReader dtrRead2 = cmdSearch.ExecuteReader();
        if (dtrRead2.Read())
        {
            PostNotificationStatus = (String)dtrRead2["isRead"];
        }

        dtrRead2.Close();
        connStr.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }

    /*After retrieve the value from the database do comparison to decide whether 
    to show the notification dialogue box*/
    if (MSGnotificationStatus.Equals("No") || PostNotificationStatus.Equals("No"))
    {
        notification.Visible = true;
        lblNPost.Text = "New Post @ Message!";
    }
    else
    {
        notification.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Like i have 2 search query. I retrieve value from the database. after I retrieve it I will take it to compare whether it is No. If is No then the notification <div> tag will display else won't display. But then now my problem is I just can read the first line of database.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of reading all the posts, use SQL to find out if there are any notifications. Your SQL will become:

```
SELECT COUNT(p.isRead) as TotalUnreadPosts 
FROM post p, thread t, person m 
WHERE m.PersonID = @pID2 AND m.PersonID = t.PersonID 
AND t.threadID = p.threadID AND p.isRead = 'No'
```

Then, to get the `TotalUnreadPosts` value use

```
int totalUnreadPosts = cmdSearch.ExecuteScalar() as int;
```

Now that you have the total of unread posts you can toggle the display of the notification:

```
if(totalUnreadPosts > 0) 
{
    notification.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: The ExecuteScalar() as int having error. there say is non nullable. May I know what the problem?